# org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable cannot be cast to org.apache.avro.mapred.AvroKey

Tags: java, spring, hadoop

I am using hadoop 2.6, spring hadoop, avro 1.7.4 to process an avro input file. But got blocked with a wired error. I have set the input file format as the avrokeyinputformat, however, hadoop still can't recognize the key Here is the stack trace:

### Stack trace

```
4-04 12:15:58 INFO    org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner map task executor complete.
04-04 12:15:59 WARN    org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner job_local1850669149_0002
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable cannot be cast to org.apache.avro.mapred.AvroKey
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:462)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:522)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable cannot be cast to org.apache.avro.mapred.AvroKey
    at com.truven.bp.data.mapred.Bdual$BdualMapper.map(Bdual.java:32)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:145)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:784)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:243)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
04-04 12:15:59 INFO    org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job Job job_local1850669149_0002 running in uber mode : false
```

### Map reduce class code is

```
import com.truven.bp.data.converter.GenericConverter;
import com.truven.bp.data.utils.Constant;
import com.truven.dataforge.paidclaims.avro.pojo.EnrollmentMonthlyEligibilityPrograms;
import org.apache.avro.mapred.AvroKey;
import org.apache.avro.mapreduce.AvroJob;
import org.apache.avro.mapreduce.AvroKeyInputFormat;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Bdual extends Configured implements Tool {

    private static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(Bdual.class);

    private static class BdualMapper extends Mapper<AvroKey<EnrollmentMonthlyEligibilityPrograms>, NullWritable, Text, NullWritable> {

        GenericConverter genericConverter = new GenericConverter();

        public void setup(Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            genericConverter.initSetup(Constant.BDUAL_FIELDS_TEXT_MAPPING_FILE_NAME);
        }

        @Override
        public void map(AvroKey<EnrollmentMonthlyEligibilityPrograms> key, NullWritable value, Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            String fields = genericConverter.convert(key.datum(), null);
            context.write(new Text(fields), NullWritable.get());
        }
    }

    private static class BdualReducer extends Reducer<Text, NullWritable, Text, NullWritable> {

        GenericConverter genericConverter = new GenericConverter();

        @Override
        public void setup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            genericConverter.initSetup(Constant.BDUAL_FIELDS_TEXT_MAPPING_FILE_NAME);
            context.write(new Text(genericConverter.getHeader()), NullWritable.get());
        }

        @Override
        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<NullWritable> values, Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            context.write(key, NullWritable.get());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Configuration conf = getConf();
        String[] otherArgs = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args).getRemainingArgs();
        if (otherArgs.length != 2) {
            System.err.println("Usage: bdual <in> <out>");
            System.exit(2);
        }

        Job job = new Job(conf, "Avro Bdual Conversion");
        job.setJarByClass(Bdual.class);

        Path inPath = new Path(args[0]);
        Path outPath = new Path(args[1]);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, inPath);
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, outPath);

        job.setInputFormatClass(AvroKeyInputFormat.class);
        job.setMapperClass(BdualMapper.class);
        AvroJob.setInputKeySchema(job, EnrollmentMonthlyEligibilityPrograms.getClassSchema());
        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(NullWritable.class);

        job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
        job.setReducerClass(BdualReducer.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(NullWritable.class);

        job.setNumReduceTasks(1);

        return (job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int result = ToolRunner.run(new Bdual(), args);
        System.exit(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: any clue will be greatly appreciated. I am waiting online ...

Comment: The job was submitted by spring hadoop with yarn

Comment: seems like the input format is still the default TextInputFormat , even I have set it to AvroKeyInputFormat

Comment: All your comments should be part of the question since they include relevant information and things that you tried.